# I wrote a function that reverses the characters of each word in a sentence, while keeping the order of the words. I'm not sure of the time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

I wrote a function that does this, and it works; however, I'm a little bit uncertain about the time complexity of my function. I feel as though it's pretty inefficient, but I'm not sure if perhaps it's just the nature of the problem. I'm imagining there is a better way to do this opposed to how I did it. My initial thought was that this would be O(n^2) time complexity, but I think it may actually be worst, because of the split function I used. What's a better way to do this? Also, am I correct in thinking that this is actually worse than O(n^2)?

```
public static String wordReverse(String string){

  //Split the string into an array such that each word is an element in the array
  String[] arr = string.split(" ");
  String result = "";

  //Iterate throught the elements in the array
    for(String value : arr){
      String word = "";

  //Reverse the letters of the element, and append them to a  temp string  
    for(int i = value.length(); i > 0; i--){
      word += value.charAt(i-1);
    }

  //Build the result string
      result += word += " ";
  } 

  //Return result string
      return(result);
}
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` instead of `+` concatenation of Strings and you'll reduce complexity from quadratic to linear.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Not true. The final bytecode results in string concatenation getting compiled down to using StringBuilder anyway. No need to hardcode it.

Comment: @Jacob The final bytecode will do no such thing. Be my guest and check it out. Java compiler doesn't do any such fancy analysis to realize that the intermediate results do not escape the method.

Comment: There is a difference. Non-inline string appending will always end up calling  NEW java/lang/StringBuilder and INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder. Otherwise if it is inline, it will simply be one LDC.

Comment: @Jacob A single concatenation expression involving more than two operands is compiled into a StringBuilder idiom, which ends with a `toString()` call, creating the string. That's the only place where you'll get a slight optimization, compared to literally creating a new string for each binary `+` operation.

Answer (score 0):

You're not worse that O(n^2). Actually, you're O(n).

split() is O(n), since it passed the array once.

You're reverse is O(n) too, since it checks all characters.

And concatenation is O(n) at worst.

Comment: But outer loop is not over entire input. So at worst case of the outer loop, the inner loop will execute only twice each time. At worst case of the inner loop, the outer loop will execute only once. Hence O(n)

Comment: There are O(n) steps taken by the combination of inner and outer loop, but the concatenation that you count as just one step is actually O(n) itself.

Comment: `String s = ""; for (char c : new char[] { 'a', 'b', ...}) s += c;` --- do you call this O(n) or O(n2)?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you treat it as O(n^2) because strings in Java are immutable. But that's implementation detail, in my opinion, since simply replacing this line with StringBuilder will negate the effect.

Comment: This question is about the implementation detail, so it's pretty much relevant. The runnimg time of the program isn't guided by abstract complexity of the general approach.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your approach is O(n) - linear time. The time increases linearly with the number of words and characters.

Comment: Okay, so my understanding is wrong. I'm a student by the way so I'm really looking for clarity. I was under the impression that when I nest a for loop the way I did, that I would have to iterate not only over the words in the array, but also each character in each element. The two loops gave my the thought that this would be o(n^2). Thanks for the info. I will do more practice with big O notation.

Comment: Nested for loops doesn't necessarily mean O(n^2). If you were iterating through you're entire input once in the outer loop and again in the inner loop then it would be n^2.  Check out how bubble sort works for example. In your case the inner loop is simply working on the next input and is not a function of the total input. Hope that helps